# Mixed-support printing?

Tags: pdf, printing, cups

I need to generate and print a document where most pages are printed over A4 labels (from the printer’s bypass tray) with some separator pages printed over plain A3 paper (from another tray).

Currently, I am using Python and Reportlab, and I know how to generate my document with mixed page size (A4 for the main pages, A3 for the separator pages). But when I print it with evince, I have to choose a page size for printing, and all pages get printing on the same page size and from the same tray…

Is there a way I can get my document to print with main and separator pages in different paper size from different tray?

Comment: There are cli tools that can list the mediabox info for each page from a pdf, and others that can split out given page numbers. You could then create 2 pdfs, one with all the A4, and another with all the A3, and send them separately to the printer. Is this the sort of solution you are looking for?

Comment: @meuh Not really. The whole document is about 6000 page long. The point of the larger separator pages is to easily split the big 6000 page batch into ~100 smaller packs that need to be sent to different recipients. If the separator pages are printed separately from the main pages, then someone will have to find the right places to split the big bundle, and that’s very error-prone.

Comment: Printing the ~100 smaller bundles one by one works; that’s what we did previously, but the experience showed it was less convenient. Moreover, we are using a shared printer. If someone else’s print job gets between some of our print jobs, it is not convenient to find it within our ~6000 pages.

Comment: I'm not sure why `evince` is being used. Can't you submit the job to cups with `lp` or `lpr`, without specifying a media size? But will your printer automatically choose the right tray if a page begins with a new size?  You should probably experiment with a simple PostScript document (which is easier to edit by hand) and search for help on `setpagedevice`

Comment: @meuh Thanks a lot for your suggestions. I did not figure out `evince` was “breaking” the file. I did not think direct printing with `lp` would work that fine for documents with mixed page sizes. Thanks also for pointing me to the `setpagedevice` PostScript command, seems to work perfectly. Will be fine, although I’d be even happier with a PDF equivalent to that `setpagedevice` command.

Comment: I think pdf can mostly be treated as a form of "packaging" for PostScript. There are tools `pdf2ps` `ps2pdf` which come with `ghostscript` to convert between the two, mostly without losing any information, but I do not know the details. I sometimes resort to converting pdf to ps, editing in some postscript, then converting back to pdf, and it works fine for the small changes I make. Also, sometimes the conversion will drastically reduce the pdf file size, as big objects that are used many times can be optimised by the conversion, when the original program failed to do so.

Comment: @meuh I just tried a `ps2pdf`/`pdf2ps` round-trip, but my `setpagedevice` commands get lost on the operation and the printing is not correct. Moreover, I was told that PDF was designed **not to be** a generic programming language like PostScript, so I don’t think you can consider PDF as “packaged” PostScript, unfortunately…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to meuh’s help, I could write a short Python program that converts the PDF I generate with my existing program to a PostScript file, with device-specific `setpagedevice` commands.

That program is quite specific for my usage, but I think it might be useful, as a starting point, for others. Here it is:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import argparse
import re
import subprocess
import sys

import PyPDF2

def make_postscript(f):
    """Convert a PDF file to PostScript, with pdf2ps, and yield it line by line."""
    with subprocess.Popen(['pdf2ps', '/dev/stdin', '/dev/stdout'], stdin=f, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None) as proc:
        for line in proc.stdout:
            yield line

def add_device_control(postscript, separator_pages):
    """Add device control commands to a PostScript file with DSC comments."""
    DSC_page_re = re.compile(b'%%Page: (?P<page_name>.+) (?P<page_number>[1-9][0-9]*)$')
    DSC_begin_page_setup_re = re.compile(b'%%BeginPageSetup$')
    page_number = None
    for line in postscript:
        m = DSC_page_re.match(line)
        if m:
            assert page_number is None
            page_number = int(m.group('page_number').decode('ASCII'))-1
            yield line
            continue
        m = DSC_begin_page_setup_re.match(line)
        if m:
            assert page_number is not None
            yield line
            if page_number in separator_pages:
                yield b'mark { << /PageSize [1191 842] /ImagingBBox null /MediaType (Plain) /MediaPosition null >> setpagedevice } stopped cleartomark\n'
            elif page_number not in separator_pages:
                yield b'mark { << /PageSize [595 842] /ImagingBBox null /MediaType (Labels) /MediaPosition 0 >> setpagedevice } stopped cleartomark\n'
            page_number = None
            continue
        yield line
    assert page_number is None

def walk_outline(outline, depth=0):
    """Walk through the outline of a PDF file in a depth-first search way, and yield each element with its zero-based depth."""
    for obj in outline:
        if isinstance(obj, PyPDF2.pdf.Destination):
            yield depth, obj
        elif isinstance(obj, list):
            for result in walk_outline(obj, depth+1):
                yield result
        else:
            assert False

def find_separator_pages(f):
    """Find the page number of the separator pages in a PDF file"""
    separator_pages = set()
    reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(f)
    for depth, obj in walk_outline(reader.outlines):
        page_num = reader._getPageNumberByIndirect(obj.page)
        if depth == 0:
            assert page_num >= 0
            separator_pages.add(page_num)
    return separator_pages

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("input_file", metavar="input.pdf", type=argparse.FileType('rb'))
    parser.add_argument("output_file", metavar="output.ps", nargs="?", type=argparse.FileType('wb'), default=sys.stdout.buffer)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    separator_pages = find_separator_pages(args.input_file)
    args.input_file.seek(0)
    postscript = make_postscript(args.input_file)
    postscript = add_device_control(postscript, separator_pages)
    for line in postscript:
        args.output_file.write(line)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Many thanks again to meuh for his help in comments.